# how for loop is working in php code

Tags: php

somebody tell me how "for loop" giving output in my script.I am new to php. I am getting confuse. why $x echo only 0 2 and 10 ? but in the second example it is giving output from 0 to 14.

```
   for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++)   
    { 
     $x= $x*2;
     echo  "$x<br>";
     $x= $x*2;
    } 
//output 0 2 10

 and  
   for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++)   
    { 
     $x= $x*2;
     echo  "$x<br>";
    }
    //output 0 2 6 14
```

Comment: This is where stepping through what your code is doing using a pen and paper to calculate every change to $x is helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at values of $x

```
                             1st Iteration  2nd Iteration 3rd Iteration  4th iteration

for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++) {   $x = 0         $x = 0+1 = 1  $x = 4+1 = 5
    $x= $x*2;                $x = 0*2 = 0   $x = 1*2 = 2  $x = 5*2 = 10
    echo  "$x<br>";          $x = 0         $x = 2        $x = 10
    $x= $x*2;                $x = 0*2 = 0   $x = 2*2 = 4  $x = 10*2 = 20
} 
//output 0 2 10

for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++) {   $x = 0         $x = 0+1      $x = 2+1 = 3   $x = 6+1 = 7
    $x= $x*2;                $x = 0*2 = 0   $x = 1*2 = 2  $x = 3*2 = 6   $x = 7*2 = 14
    echo  "$x<br>";          $x = 0         $x = 2        $x = 6         $x = 14
}
//output 0 2 6 14
```

Answer (score 2):

Because in your first loop you have `$x= $x*2;` 2 times and in second example, just one.

---

`0x2 = 0`, output `0` and then again `x = 0*2` what is `0` too.

After this cycle is value of `x` increased by `1`. So `x = 1` => `1x2` outputs `2` and then you set `x = 2*2` what is `4`.

**But you probably ask, why next is not `4x2 = 8` but `10`?** Because of for loop. You forgot you are using for loop and in each cycle is value of `x` variable increased by `1`. So, `(4+1)x2 = 10`

And also I must recommend to you that **you shouldn't edit values** of these variables, which are used in for cycles. Some languages will throw you an error if you try do this.

Answer (score 2):

$x= $x*2;
echo  "$x
";
$x= $x*2;

0

*** `0` //echo ; ***

0

1*2 = 2

*** `2` //echo ; ***

2*2 = 4

4+(1 from loop increment)*2 = 10

*** `10` //echo ; ***

10*2 = 20

Part 2 
$x= $x*2
echo  "$x
";

0

*** `0` //echo ***

1*2 = 2

*** `2` //echo ***

2+(1 loop increment) * 2= 6

`6` //echo;

6+1  * 2= 14

*** `14` //echo; ***

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++)   
    { 
     $x= $x*2;
     echo  "$x<br>";
     $x= $x*2;
    }
```

So the code goes as

```
step1 : $x= 0 , then $x*2 = 0; $x= $x*2 = 0, $x++ = 1 
step2 : $x=1 , then $x*2 = 2 ; $x= $x*2 = 4 $x++ = 5
step3 : $x=5 , then $x*2 = 10 ; $x= $x*2 = 20  $x++ = 21
step4 : $x= 21 which is less than 10 and loop breaks and you get the output as
```

0 2 10

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because your running your multiplication twice:

The first loop does this:

```
// start x at 0; run while x is less than or equal to 10; at end of loop increase x by one 
                                 |  First Loop     |  Second Loop    |  Third Loop       |  Fourth Loop      |
for($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {    |  x = 0          |  x = 1          |  x = 5            |                   |
    $x = $x * 2;                 |  x = 0 * 2 = 0  |  x = 1 * 2 = 2  |  x = 5 * 2 = 10   |                   |       
    echo "$x<br>";               |  x = 0          |  x = 2          |  x = 10           |                   |
    $x = $x * 2;                 |  x = 0 * 2 = 0  |  x = 2 * 2 = 4  |  x = 10 * 2 = 20  |                   |
    // EOL, we add 1 to x;       |  x = 0 + 1 = 1  |  x = 4 + 1 = 5  |  x = 20 + 1 = 21  |                   |
}

for($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {    |  x = 0          |  x = 1          |  x = 3            |  x = 7            |
    $x = $x * 2;                 |  x = 0 * 2 = 0  |  x = 1 * 2 = 2  |  x = 3 * 2 = 6    |  x = 7 * 2 = 14   |       
    echo "$x<br>";               |  x = 0          |  x = 2          |  x = 6            |  x = 14           |
    // EOL, we add 1 to x;       |  x = 0 + 1 = 1  |  x = 2 + 1 = 3  |  x = 6 + 1 = 7    |  x = 14 + 1 = 15  |
}
```

Comment: Thanks to @MarkBaker for the nicer way to lay it out, rather than the line by line I had before.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish, but try to seperate the $x within the forloop, from the $x you're using to iterate. Try something like this:

```
for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++)   
    { 
     $y= $x*2;
     echo  "$y<br>";
     $y= $y*2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is the $x is the counter vaiarble for your loop and it gets incremented througth the $x++ expersion by one but you override this value with your multiplications so the loop-code isnt executed 11 times. Use $y = $x*2; echo "$y
" instead. So your loop index whont be manipulated